# Is it possible to grab the default values stored and sent by Mixpanel?

Tags: javascript, analytics, mixpanel

I have implemented Mixpanel into my web application, and had noticed that they store a set of `super properties`  , which is essentially everything below

> Engagement
>
> 1. City ($city) - The city of the event sender, parsed from IP.
> 2. Region ($region) - The region (state or province) of the event sender, parsed from IP.
> 3. Country (mp_country_code) - The country of the event sender, parsed from IP.
> 4. Browser ($browser) - Browser name (not versioned).
> 5. Browser Version ($browser_version) - Browser version number.
> 6. Device ($device) - The name of the event sender's device, if they're on mobile web.
> 7. Current URL ($current_url) - The full URL of the webpage on which the event is triggered.
> 8. Initial Referrer ($initial_referrer) - Referring URL at first arrival.
> 9. Initial Referring Domain ($initial_referring_domain) - Referring domain at first arrival.
> 10. Operating System ($os) - OS of the event sender.
> 11. Mixpanel Library (mp_lib) - Mixpanel Library that sent the event.
> 12. Referrer ($referrer) - Referring URL, including your own domain.
> 13. Referring Domain ($referring_domain) - Referring domain, including your own domain.
> 14. Screen Height ($screen_height) - The height of the screen of the device.
> 15. Screen Width ($screen_width) - The width of the screen of the device.
> 16. Search Engine ($search_engine) - Search engine a customer used when they arrived at your domain.
> 17. Search Keyword (mp_keyword) - Search keywords detected on the referrer from a search engine to your domain.
> 18. UTM Parameters (utm_source, utm_medium, etc.) - Any utm tags associated with the link a customer clicked to arrive at your domain.
>       Each utm will be collected under its own property.1.

[Mixpanel default values - FAQ](https://mixpanel.com/help/questions/articles/what-properties-do-mixpanels-libraries-store-by-default)

What I want to know, is it possible to grab and store these same values for my own personal use, for example to send over to my own backend?

I had a look through their docs and haven't found anything related to being able to do this, so i thought i would ask to see if anyone has achieved this or knows how it could be done.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the module [ClientJS](https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/clientjs) today it allows you to both create a digital fingerprint and access the data-points used to create the fingerprint itself.

Example code:

```
  var client = new ClientJS();

  client.getBrowserData();
  client.getFingerprint();
  client.getCustomFingerprint(...);
```

I also found [Inbound](https://www.npmjs.com/package/inbound) Which is a referrer parsing library for node.js / express web apps.

Example code:

```
var inbound = require('inbound'),
    express = require('express');

var app = express();

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  var referrer = req.header('referrer');
  var href = req.url;
  inbound.referrer.parse(href, referrer, function (err, desc) {
    req.referrer = desc;
    next(err);
  });
});

app.use(app.router);

app.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  return res.send(req.referrer);
});

var port = 8000;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Server listening on port : ' + port);
```